# When when sql must specify the source table for a variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am pretty new in SQL and I am using sqlzoo for practice and in their  [AdventureWorks #14](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/AdventureWorks_hard_questions) I used the codes below and it did not work

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID), SUM(SubTotal),RANGE FROM
(SELECT SalesOrderID,SubTotal,
        CASE WHEN SubTotal<99
        THEN '0-99'
        WHEN SubTotal <999
        THEN '100-999'
        WHEN SubTotal < 9999
        THEN '1000-9999'
        ELSE '10000-'
        END AS 'RANGE'
FROM SalesOrderHeader) as new
GROUP BY RANGE
```

However when I changed the code to

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID), SUM(SubTotal),new.RANGE FROM
(SELECT SalesOrderID,SubTotal,
        CASE WHEN SubTotal<99
        THEN '0-99'
        WHEN SubTotal <999
        THEN '100-999'
        WHEN SubTotal < 9999
        THEN '1000-9999'
        ELSE '10000-'
        END AS 'RANGE'
FROM SalesOrderHeader) as new
GROUP BY new.RANGE
```

It worked by declaring the source table of `RANGE` I am just wondering when do I have to declare the source of the variable since `RANGE` is unique in the derivative table? Is that because that it is a derivative table or because it is a scalar?

Another question is when do we have to give a derivative table a new name?

Comment: Just a small little tip. If you're learning SQL you're better off using a database that resembles the SQL standard a little more closely like PostgreSQL. MySQL gives a lot of freedom but because of that teaches you mostly MySQL instead of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANGE` is a reserved word in MySQL.  You can see the list [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html).

Because it is a reserved word, when you just use `RANGE`, you confuse the parser.  If you have `new.RANGE`, then the parser can figure out that you mean a column.

Here are some rules to help you write better code:

- Avoid the use of reserved words for table and column names.
- It is good practice to use qualified column names (that is, use the table alias).
- Don't use single quotes for column names.  If you have to escape the name, use backticks in MySQL (and the appropriate escape character in other databases).

I would suggest writing your query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID), SUM(SubTotal), soh.TheRange
FROM (SELECT SalesOrderID, SubTotal,
             (CASE WHEN SubTotal < 99 THEN '0-99'
                   WHEN SubTotal < 999 THEN '100-999'
                   WHEN SubTotal < 9999 THEN '1000-9999'
                   ELSE '10000-'
              END) AS TheRange
      FROM SalesOrderHeader
     ) soh
GROUP BY soh.TheRange;
```

Or, dispense with the subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID), SUM(SubTotal),
       (CASE WHEN SubTotal < 99 THEN '0-99'
             WHEN SubTotal < 999 THEN '100-999'
             WHEN SubTotal < 9999 THEN '1000-9999'
             ELSE '10000-'
        END) AS TheRange
FROM SalesOrderHeader soh
GROUP BY TheRange;
```

You may also notice that I always use `as` for column aliases and never use `as` for table aliases.

Comment: I have one doubt If suppose @MYjx has use 'rrr' as new column then it was not required to use alias.rrr. Please clear my doubt?

Comment: @HardikParmar . . . It is not required to use table aliases if the column can be unambiguously determined to come from one table or subquery (and you'll notice I didn't use them in the last examples).  I meant it is good practice to use them, and I made that change.